# ValueError: no se pudo convertir la cadena en flotante: b'3.23 0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de graficar los valores de una señal proveniente de arduino pero cuando trato de graficar los datos me manda un mensaje como se indica en el titulo de la pregunta, no comprendo muy bien el porque sucede ya que el tipo de datos que llegan a python son cadenas de caracteres y las trato de convertir a flotante para poder graficarlo espero alguien me pueda explicar que sucede, anexo el codigo.

```
**Codigo de python**
import serial
import time
import collections
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D 
import numpy as np

def getSerialData(self,Samples,numData,serialConnection,lines):
    for i in range(numData):
        value=float(serialConnection.readline().strip())
        data[i].append(value)
        lines[i].set_data(range(Samples),data[i])

serialPort='COM5'
bauRate=9600

try:
    serialConnection=serial.Serial(serialPort,bauRate)
except:
    print('No es posible conectarse al puerto')

Samples=200
sampleTime=100
numData=2
xmin=0
xmax=Samples
ymin=[0,0,-50,0]
ymax=[6,6,50,100]
lines=[]
data=[]
for i in range(numData):
    data.append(collections.deque([0]*Samples,maxlen=Samples))
    lines.append(Line2D([],[],color='blue'))

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1,xlim=(xmin,xmax),ylim=(ymin[0],ymax[0]))
ax1.title.set_text('Primer grafica')
ax1.set_xlabel('Samples')
ax1.set_ylabel('voltaje')
ax1.add_line(lines[0])

ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2,xlim=(xmin,xmax),ylim=(ymin[1],ymax[1]))
ax2.title.set_text('segunda grafica')
ax2.set_xlabel("Samples")
ax2.set_ylabel('voltaje')
ax2.add_line(lines[1])

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,getSerialData,fargs=(Samples,numData,serialConnection,lines), interval=sampleTime)
plt.show()

serialConnection.close()
```

En este codigo de arduino(se anexa abajo) estoy ocupando tanto la entrada analógica A0 y A1 cada una realiza un proceso diferente en donde una hace un proceso de detección de picos mientras que la otra solo me ayuda a graficar la señal, las variables que mando a python son estas:

```
Serial.print(voltageValue);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.println(z);
```

el Serial.print que esta entre ambas variables me ayuda a que ambas se puedan graficar al mismo tiempo en el serial plotter de arduino

**codigo de arduino**

```
/*
*/
const int analogInPin=A1; // Pin analogio a utilizar 
int sensorValue=0;   //almacenamiento de las lecturas del potenciometro de 0 a 1023
float voltageValue=0; // almacenar la conversion del dato a voltaje
unsigned long lastTime=0, sampleTime=70; //Dato se envia cada cierto tiempo del muestro
float factor = 0.75;    // coeficiente para filtro pasa bajos
float maximo = 0.0;   // para almacenar valor maximo 
int minimoEntreLatidos = 300; // 300 mseg. de tiempo minimo entre latidos
float valorAnterior = 500;  // para almacenar valor previo
int latidos = 0;    // contador de cantidad de latidos
int z=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   // inicializacion de monitor serie a 9600 bps
  //Serial.println("ECG\tMedicones"); // texto a mostrar
}

void loop() {
  static unsigned long tiempoLPM = millis();  // tiempo Latidos Por Minuto con
            // valor actual devuelto por millis()
  static unsigned long entreLatidos = millis(); // tiempo entre Latidos con
            // valor actual devuelto por millis()

  int valorLeido = analogRead(A0);    // lectura de entrada analogica A0

  float valorFiltrado = factor * valorAnterior + (1 - factor) * valorLeido; // filtro pasa bajos
  float cambio = valorFiltrado - valorAnterior;   // diferencia entre valor filtrado y
              // valor anterior
  valorAnterior = valorFiltrado;    // actualiza valor anterior con valor filtrado

  if ((cambio >= maximo) && (millis() > entreLatidos + minimoEntreLatidos)) { // si cambio es
          // es mayor o igual a maximo y pasaron al menos 300 mseg.
    maximo = cambio;      // actualiza maximo con valor de cambo
    entreLatidos = millis();    // actualiza variable entreLatidos con millis()
    latidos++;        // incrementa latidos en uno
  }
  maximo = maximo * 0.97;   // carga maximo como el 97 por ciento de su propio
          // valor para dejar decaer y no perder pulsos
  if (millis() >= tiempoLPM + 5000) {    // si transcurrieron al menos 15 segundos
    //Serial.print("Latidos por minuto: "); // muestra texto
   z=(latidos * 12);    // muestra variable latidos multiplicado por 4
    latidos = 0;        // coloca contador de latidos en cero
    tiempoLPM = millis();     // actualiza variable con valor de millis()
  }

  //delay(50);   // demora entre lecturas de entrada analogica
    delay(100);
if(millis()-lastTime>sampleTime){  //Verificar si el tiempo transcurrido es el tiempo de muestreo 
lastTime=millis();
  //lectura de los potenciometros
sensorValue=analogRead(analogInPin);
 
  // conversion de cero a 5 voltios 
voltageValue=scaling(sensorValue,0,1023,0,5);
  //voltageValue[1]=scaling(sensorValue[1],0,1023,0,5);
  // Envias datos a python
//Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(voltageValue);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.println(z);
  }
  
}
//formula para el escalamiento de la variable  
float scaling(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max )
{
  return(x-in_min)*(out_max-out_min)/(in_max-in_min)+out_min;
  }
```

Comment: los que te esta llegando son cadenas de caracteres en tipo bytes as intentado un `str(b'3.23 0')[2:-1]`

Comment: Por favor, añade información concreta del error que te devuelve el intérprete de python (línea donde salta/o sentencia concreta donde crees que está el error). Tú llevas tiempo trabajando con este código y te es familiar, pero los demás no.

Comment: Falta ver que estás mandando desde Arduino. Da la impresión qué recibes una secuencia interminable de valores. El código muestra que requieres un valor por línea. ¿Puedes publicar la parte pertinente del Arduino, donde formas y envias la información?

Comment: les comparto el código de Arduino

Answer (score 0):

Según parece, cada línea enviada por Arduino consiste de dos valores: la lectura y un cero. Puedes separarlos con

```
linea = serialConnection.readline()
lect, z = linea.split()
lectura = float(lect)
```

La línea contiene dos valores separados por espacios, que `split()` separa y devuelve. El primer valor lo recibimos en `lect` y el segundo en 'z'. Luego transformas `lect`, que es un string, en un valor flotante.